# database is not getting autoloaded upon specific kind of 404 routing in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, routes, http-status-code-404, autoload

I have a controller called `Hello.php` that has only one method called `world`. The controller starts a transaction at `construct` time and the `world` function echo `hello world` and commits the transaction.

```
class Hello extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->db->trans_begin;
    }

    public function world(){
        echo "hello world";
        $this->db->trans_commit;
    }
}
```

PLEASE NOTE THAT: my database has been autoloaded from config/autoload.php with `$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');`

---

From the `config/routes.php` I have routed my 404 errors to a controller called bad_parameters.php with `$route['404_override'] = 'bad_parameters'`;

---

```
class Bad_parameters extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index(){
        echo "before rollback - ";
        $this->db->trans_rollback();
        echo "after rollback";
    }
}
```

---

Now I am going to do 3 things:

1. Call to `hello/world` - expecting `Hello World` then COMMIT
2. Call to `hello/fake` - expecting 404 routing and then `before rollback - after rollback`
3. Call to `fake/fake` - expecting 404 routing and then `before rollback - after rollback`

**INSTEAD**, this is what happens

1. Call to `hello/world` - getting `Hello World` then COMMIT as expected
2. Call to `hello/fake` - getting `before rollback` <-- **my question is about this**
3. Call to `fake/fake` - getting `before rollback - after rollback`  as expected

The error message that i get at point no. 2 is:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: Bad_parameters::$db
>
> Filename: controllers/bad_parameters.php

It is saying the $db was undefined whereas I DID autoload the database from `config/autoload.php`.

NOW, if i include `$this->load->database();` in the CONSTRUCTOR of `bad_parameters.php`, then point no 2 shows 'before rollback - after rollback' as expected without any error.

Even though BOTH no.2 and no.3 are 404 routings, no.3 example is working fine but the no.2 example is having this issue. Why should this happen? I am already autoloading my database.

Comment: Have you looked at your PHP error log? A 500 error should show up there

Comment: i found something... there is an issue with db->trans_rollback()... let me update the question. At the point no 2 that i mentioned, the PHP execution is stopping because trans_rollback is not happening at point no. 2

Comment: What's the trans_rollback error which you're seeing?

Comment: okay..... i dug FURTHER MORE....... i realize it's an autoloading issue..... database is not getting autoloaded...... i am updating the question

Comment: you could add a pre_system hook to possibly correct it.  Now that you mention it I've noticed something similiar happen in a framework I made with 404 route defined.  could be an error in application  flow.  routing is the second thing supposed to happen

Comment: if youre not too far along with your project though i'd say try a fresh install as that context usually works and you can really only break it by customizing the default ci install.

Answer (score 1):

which CI version you're using? try to update your CI version.

at CI 2.1.0 had fixed a bug (Reactor #19) where 1) the 404_override route was being ignored in some cases, and 2) auto-loaded libraries were not available to the 404_override controller when a controller existed but the requested method did not.

[ci changelog](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/changelog.html)

[ci upgrading](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrading.html)

Comment: i am using CI 2.0.3 - perhaps this IS the main issue. Will try upgrading to CI 2.1.0 and comment later.

Answer (score 0):

Here I found a fix for this:

https://bitbucket.org/ellislab/codeigniter-reactor/changeset/2fa0e75a2101

For preserving this answer:

replace (system/core/CodeIgniter.php) line 292 :

```
show_404("{$class}/{$method}");
```

with (system/core/CodeIgniter.php) line 292 :

```
// Check and see if we are using a 404 override and use it.
if ( ! empty($RTR->routes['404_override']))
{
    $x = explode('/', $RTR->routes['404_override']);
    $class = $x[0];
    $method = (isset($x[1]) ? $x[1] : 'index');
}
else
{
    show_404("{$class}/{$method}");
}
```

and replace (system/core/Router.php) line 273 :

```
if (!empty($this->routes['404_override']))
```

with (system/core/Router.php) line 273 :

```
if ( ! empty($this->routes['404_override']))
```

Comment: but wouldn't modifying the files inside the `SYSTEM` folder be a NO... NO...?

Comment: at [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html) it says **Most users will never have any need to do this, but the option to replace or extend them does exist for those who would like to significantly alter the CodeIgniter core.**

Comment: so, you can write an alterator class to replace the original methods, and you still won't modify the core files. The changes I've given to you would be a waypoint for which methods to override in your alterator class.